# Поиск атрибутов у элементов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не понимаю, почему выделяет всю строку, если я написал, что надо найти ссылку с атрибутов href и эта ссылка может состоять из многих символов. И по идеи должно выделить до элемента img, а выделяет почти всю строку, как сделать правильно?

```
<a href="user/111/444"><img src="/GI_EN.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Двигатель на Портер2" title="Двигатель на Портер2"></a>
```

Регулярное выражение

```
<a href=".+">
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно что вы хотите сделать и что сделали

Comment: хочу вывести содержимое атрибута title

Comment: Надо или убрать жадность, или переписать шаблон на отрицание кавычки. В первом варианте нужно после плюса поставить знак вопроса, а во втором написать внутри кавычек символьный класс с отрицанием: `[^"]+`

Comment: А для тайтла тогда и дописать его в шаблон нужно.

Comment: для href тоже надо, как сделать, что бы черту, тоже учитывал? <a href="[a-z/0-9]+">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию модификаторы `+` и `?` работают в "жадном" режиме. Т.е. они захватывают **максимальное** число символов, которое удовлетворяет данном регулярному выражению. Т.к. Вы сказали искать любые символы, пока не встретятся `">` то Вы и получаете поиск до **последней** такой пары символов. Если же Вам нужно найти **первую** пару символов, то Вам нужен "не жадный" режим.

Этот режим включается модификатором `?` который добавляется после модификаторов `+`, `*`

Итого, Ваше регулярное выражение должно иметь вид

```
<a href=".+?">
```

Comment: спасибо, всё время забываю использование регулярных выражений

Comment: Два минуса. За что?

Comment: я плюсовал, не знаю, кто минусы ставил